# I heard "geezer" (?) on "Rumpole of the Bailey"

Tags: meaning

I heard "geezer" (?) on "Rumpole of the Bailey" as a character said that her husband, who she was feuding with, had "locked the geezer" (unsure of spelling)...or locked "her geezer"...It was NOT used as a reference to an old man !

Comment: The word [geezer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geezer) has multiple meanings, not all of which specify an old man.

Comment: Geyser is a term that one sometimes hears from British speakers. The Wikipedia article below may help  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_heating

Answer (score 4):

Before central heating became common, people often used to have small wall-mounted gas water heaters in their bathroom or kitchen, known as 'geysers' after the famous hot springs. If you are certain it doesn't refer to a man, this is the most likely interpretation.

Comment: Thanks ! I think your answer is what I was looking for. Rumpole clearly pronounced it "geezer" which must be the British pronunciation of "geyser"...I'm American and fascinated with British/English words that are different than ours for similar things ! I've been keeping track of words and phrases I hear as I watch British TV and movies and look them up and put them into a file as i go along. For instance we say "driver's license" while Brits mostly say "driving license" and stuff like "Grass him up" = Squeal on him...turn him in...or "handbags at 10 paces" LOL ...I must have 8 pages so far !

Answer (score 1):

In some Rumpole episodes, a "geezer" is a London term for, perhaps, a fashionable man - "he's a geezer".

In the episode I think you refer to - "Rumpole and the Married Lady" with Phyllida Law - where a couple are divorcing and have not spoken to each other for years - the word intended is "geyser" and is pronounced "gee-suh" or "gee-zuh" with a hard 'g' and means the hot water faucet. Do Americans perhaps pronounce it "guy-suh"?

Comment: Well done! I remember this question from years ago. The quote in John Mortimer's book, Rumpole of the Bailey, is in fact "Anyone's mother in Ruislip must surely be better than with a chartered accountant [who locks up the geyser!](https://books.google.it/books?id=03ODDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT118&lpg=PT118&dq=%22locks+up+the+geyser%22+%22Rumpole+of+the+bailey%22&source=bl&ots=K67p3ixSy8&sig=ACfU3U00CmU7lUJdOc30H1bu9O7765GCuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsg_HL0KGEAxWS1AIHHQQwCy4Q6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22locks%20up%20the%20geyser%22%20%22Rumpole%20of%20the%20bailey%22&f=false)"

Comment: We pronounce *geyser* exactly like we do the last two syllables of *disguiser*: phonemically /ˈɡaɪzər/ [per the OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/geyser_n#pronunciation). The OED further says that the UK pronunciations include only /ˈɡiːzə/, /ˈɡʌɪzə/, /ˈɡeɪsə/, and /ˈɡʌɪsə/ (likely because they disavow and disregard their own rhotic speakers ). So that’s the same vowel as we have in *guy* — plus it has to have a "proper R"  at the end for all but the few remaining non-rhotic speakers among us here. See also [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geyser#Pronunciation_2).

Comment: I don't know who "we" are, @tchrist but I (brought up in Middlesex and now a Yorkshireman) have always pronounced _geyser_ the same as _geezer_, whether it means a hot fountain or a hot-water boiler on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

In UK slang geezer (or geeza) can just mean a man, regardless of age, like 'chap' or 'bloke'.

In the context of Rumpole of the Bailey, I'm guessing she's saying that he "locked her man up" (put her husband/partner/boyfriend in jail).